fetch: set Accept-Encoding and honor Content-Encoding
I am sending a fetch request for a .br brotli compressed file:
const resp = await fetch("/hello-world.wasm.br")

In the Chrome network tab I see that there is no Accept-Encoding header.
The server responds with the correct Content-Encoding header but the browser does not decompress the response.
How can I get fetch to use the compressed content encoding?

You can explicitly set the Accept-Encoding header in your fetch request as below:
const resp = await fetch("hello-world.wasm.br", 
{
   headers: {
       "Accept-Encoding" : Here you specify the supported content encoding
   }
})

For more information about fetch-api:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch


This does not work since Accept-Encoding is a forbidden header: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name

It ain't a ChatGPT answer. My bad for the answer and thanks for the forbidden header link

Here i found an interesting link about response compression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Unfortunately that does not solve the question.  I would not have asked the question unless I had a specific issue w/ fetch() not sending nor respecting Accept-Encoding and Content-Encoding.
